# In which variable are past sparse tree queries saved

Tags: org-mode, history, history-variables

I'm executing sparse tree queries programmatically, and I'd like to save the search queries in the same history variable that org-mode uses by default. I'm guessing I can/should do this with `add-to-history` (described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Minibuffer-History.html)).

I took a quick look at the code but, being unfamiliar with it, I could not find the right variable.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the variable `org-tags-history`, so the following works:

```
 (add-to-history 'org-tags-history query-string)
```